# Картинку из одного ViewController отправить в другой

Tags: xcode, изображения, objective-c

Подскажите, есть ViewController с кнопкой и ImageView. При нажитии кнопки в ImageView загружается картинка с веба. Вопрос, как эту картинку показать в другом ViewController? Спасибо.

View1.h

```
@interface asdViewController :
 UIViewController {

     IBOutlet UIButton *actBtnGet;

      } @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;

@end
```

View1.m

```
#import "asdViewController.h"

@interface asdViewController ()

@end

@implementation asdViewController

- (IBAction)actBtnGet:(id)sender {
    id path = @"http://host.ru/123.png";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    self.ImageView.image=img;

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: @slake, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ээ, а так??

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TwoVCSeque"])
    {
        TwoViewController *twoVC = (TwoViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        twoVC.img = self.img;
    }
}
```

Вопрос кажется или слишком простым или я вас не понял))

Вообще основное здесь это:

```
twoVC.img = self.img;
```

Остальное вы реализовываете, как вам надо, вобщем то...

Comment: Стыдно, но я затупил на этом месте) Учимся потихоньку просто) Спасибо))

Comment: @slake, всегда пожалуйста ;)

Comment: Тут такое дело, xcode ругается на эту строчку ' twoVC.img = self.img; '. Говорит "Use of undeclared identifier 'img' ". Почему? Об этом 'img' же говорится в кнопке или нет?

Comment: @slake, @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *img;

А в кнопке надо подправить self.img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wl3yitdknoq6nus/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-07-10%2000.00.40.png

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо))

Comment: @slake, ну и круто :)