# По нажитию кнопки вывести картинку кодом на втором View

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Подскажите пжст что я не так сделал??Хочу нажатием кнопки вывести картинку кодом на другом контролере!!!
Первый :
//  ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
 - (IBAction)buttonSurprise:(id)sender;
```

//  ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImage*picker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageName;
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (IBAction)buttonSurprise:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.picker = [UIImage imageNamed: @"vk-group-250x240.jpg"];
    self.imageName.image= self.picker;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueOne"])
    {
        DetailViewController *twoVC = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        twoVC.img = self.picker;
        }}

@end
```

Второй:
//  DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bigImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *bigText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage*img;
```

//  DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface DetailViewController ()
@end
@implementation DetailViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
       // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  self.bigImage.image = self.img;
    }
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

Comment: Для форматирования кода выделите его мышкой и нажмите кнопку `{}`.

Comment: Дауж каша вышла!!вот скрины:
https://yadi.sk/i/PsZpF6nUWXexu
https://yadi.sk/i/kJGWblFzWXexT
https://yadi.sk/i/XdOn1sYpWXewW
https://yadi.sk/i/_6zH61H6WXeur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Юзайте поиск иногда: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/334220](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/334220/objective-c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-viewcontroller-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9)

2) Все должно работать, пара строк то - брейкпоинт и смотрите, что и где у вас не получается. Условие то хоть выполняется?

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueOne"])
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!Я как раз и делал по аналогии, в программирование две недели, еще не умею проверять выполняются ли условия либо нет.Попробую еще в туториалах поискать. 

Comment: @SergeyXcode, а как вы это писали: 

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueOne"])
    {
        DetailViewController *twoVC = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        twoVC.img = self.picker;
        }

Comment: все я понял про что имели ввиду, выполняется---прощелкнул принудительно брекпойнд и все получилось--спасибо, осталось научиться брекпойды исправлять)

Comment: @SergeyXcode, ну и славненько))